# Foreach перебор значений и отправка в бд.что исправить как наладить?

Tags: mysql, циклы, foreach, php, sql

```
<form method="post" action="" name='sss[]'>
    <label>Введите название новости:</label>
    <input type="text" name="designed[]" /><br />
    <label>Введите автора:</label>
    <input type="text" name="designed[]" /><br />
    <label>Введите дату публикации:</label>
    <input type="text" name="designed[]" /><br />

    <label>Введите ключевые слова:</label>
    <input type="text" name="designed[]" /><br />

    <label>Введите ключевые слова:</label>
    <input type="text" name="designed[]" /><br />

    <label>Введите ключевые слова:</label>
    <input type="text" name="designed[]" /><br />
     <label>Введите ключевые слова:</label>
    <input type="text" name="designed[]" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="add" />
</form>
<?php include "../db.php";
if(isset($_POST['add']) or die(mysql_error()))
    {
        foreach ($_POST['designed'] as $key => $value) {
            $date=mysql_query("insert into 'назначенные' ('номер группы','дисциплина','тип работы',
        'имя работы','номер работы','дата сдачи','макс балл') value ('$value','$value','$value','$value','$value','$value','$value')");
                                }
}
?>
```

Не знаю что делать с запросов в форич....help me

Comment: Хм... Отсыпь своей дури...

Для чего здесь вообще цикл? Какова цель использования?

Comment: А в чём проблема?

Comment: А мне нравится!)

    ('$value','$value','$value','$value','$value','$value','$value')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эм, а что мешает поставить полям РАЗНЫЕ имена? :)
Цикл - даже не буду спрашивать, зачем он тут.

Comment: эм
как знаписать данные из форм в таблицу через массив?

Comment: $_POST['имя поля']

Comment: $date=mysql_query("insert into 'назначенные' ('номер группы','дисциплина','тип работы',
        'имя работы','номер работы','дата сдачи','макс балл') value ('$_POST['designed')"); но ведь не то?